# fmt.Sprintf update database

Tags: postgresql, go, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate a string to update my database, but I'm not able to capture the values ​​with sprinf %s

```
if email.Event == "dropped" || email.Event == "bounce" || email.Event == "deferred" {
            email.Reason = email.Reason
            var reason = email.Reason
            var sgID = email.SgMessageId

            var teste = fmt.Sprintf("update email set erro = concat(erro,' ',%s) where id_sendgrid=%s", reason, sgID)
        fmt.Println(teste)

            _, err := h.DB.Exec(teste)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal("Erro ao realizar upload no email com evento ERROR")

            }
            fmt.Println(email.Reason, email.SgMessageId, email.Response)
        }
```

I can capture the id_sendgrid value, but I can't get the value of this part here --> (error,' ' %s)

this error appears in my console:

update email set error = concat(error,' ',) + where id_sendgrid=14c5d75ce93

Comment: Seems like `reason` is an empty string

Comment: it's not, it's populated, I don't know what to do anymore

Comment: Note that using Sprintf for query strings is very dangerous. It's better to use query parameters whenever possible.

Comment: If the output you've provided is accurate, then `reason` absolutely is empty, as @tkausl said. If it's not empty, then that means the message you pasted was not generated by your program.

Comment: What Peter said. Never apply users' input to build queries. See https://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 2):

Do not use Sprintf to build database queries. Use parameterized queries instead:

```
_, err := h.DB.Exec(`update email set erro = concat(erro, ' ', $1) where id_sendgrid = $2`,
    reason, sgID)
```

`$1`, `$2` and so forth are automatically replaced by the additional arguments to Exec.